# Struct pointers behaving differently in two different functions, not sure why

Tags: c

I'm running into an issue where my "TEST INSIDE BUILD" works but not "TEST OUTSIDE."  A fragment of the code is here

```
command_t build_op_command(unsigned code, command_t comone, command_t comtwo)
{
  commad_t s;
  s=malloc(sizeof(*s));
  switch(code)
  {
    case 5:
      s->type=SEQUENCE_COMMAND;
    ...
  }
  s->status=-1;
  s->input=NULL;
  s->output=NULL;
  s->u.command[0]=comone;
  s->u.command[1]=comtwo;
  printf("TEST INSIDE BUILD: %d  and %s",s->u.command[0]->type, s->u.command[0]->u.word[0]);
  s->u.word=NULL;
  s->u.subshell_command=NULL; //not yet implemented
  return s;
  }
```

and

```
...
command_t op_command;
op_command=build_op_command(op_pop(op_s),comone,comtwo);
printf("TEST OUTSIDE: %d  and %s",op_command->u.command[0]->type,op_command->u.command[0]->u.word[0]);
...
```

command_t is a pointer for struct command.  I'm not quite sure why it would correctly inside the build function, but not work correctly outside of it.  Any input would be greatly appreciated. I run into a segmentation fault, I've tried allocating space for s->u.word, but that didn't seem to help anything.

```
struct command
{
  enum command_type type;
  int status;
  char *input;
  char *output;

  union
  {
    struct command *command[2];
    char **word;
    struct command *subshell_command;
  } u;
};

typeder struct command *command_t;
```

Comment: Is `u` a union by any chance?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry for being vague.  Coding got extremely hard, and I can't seem to understand what's going on.  Maybe I would need to allocate space for the union, but that wouldn't make sense cause I've storing u.word alright without issues.

Comment: You'lll find the same problem if you move your test to after `s->u.word=NULL;`  , it's nothing to do with functions

Comment: You're absolutely right.  The placement of s->u.word=NULL impacts the code.  So if my understanding is correct, s->u.word == s->command[0]->u.word == s->command[1]->word, if so then why do they printout different strings?

Comment: `s->u.command[0]` and `s->u.command[1]` are different. `command` overlaps with `word`, but `command` is not itself a union, so `command[0]` and `command[1]` are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not give enough information, post the definition of `command_t`.

`u` is probably a `union`:

```
s->u.command[0]=comone;
s->u.command[1]=comtwo;
printf("TEST INSIDE BUILD: %d  and %s",s->u.command[0]->type, s->u.command[0]->u.word[0]);
```

After the first printf, you initialize other members of this `union` and override the `command`:

```
s->u.word=NULL;
s->u.subshell_command=NULL; //not yet implemented
```

The next `printf` report different contents.

All members of a `union` share the same location in memory, you cannot use more than one member at a time.

Comment: So in this case all three commands will be sharing the same union space?  This is the first time dealing with union, which is confusing me.  So all commands created within this scope all share the same union?  If so then I can sort of see why s->u.command[0]->u.word[0] may cause issues, but how come s->u.command[0]->type is creating issues as well?

Comment: @Jack: all members of each `union u` share the same space.  You cannot initialize more than one of them, and should only read the one you have written.  Different instances of this `union` are disjoint if they are indeed allocated correctly.  In your case, the `type` member of the `command_t` structure is supposed to tell you which member of `u` to access.